# VBA: Parse preceding numbers from string

Tags: vba

I need to parse into two substrings a string that always starts with numeric text followed by alpha-numeric text. The strings can vary a bit, but not too much. Below are examples of incoming format and the strings I need:

```
"00 10 50 Information to Bidders"   ==> "00 10 50", "Information to Bidders"
"001050 Information to Bidders"     ==> "001050", "Information to Bidders"    
"00 10 50 - Information to Bidders" ==> "00 10 50", "Information to Bidders"
"001050 -- Information to Bidders"  ==> "001050", "Information to Bidders"
```

I was hoping it would only be a half dozen lines of VBA, but my code is turning into a loop where I'm testing every character in the string to see where the changeover from numeric-only to non-numeric, then parsing the string based on the changeover location. Not a big deal, but messier than I was hoping for. Are there VBA functions that would eliminate the need to iterate through each string character?

Comment: Is there always spaces between the numbers and the letters?  If so, you can split the data on the spaces and the search the first character for a number or letter.  Recombine to parse the data correctly.

Comment: This is off topic here and has been tagged to be moved to the correct area. Please don't double post. In the meantime, to improve your post so you get an accurate answer; VBA is VB for Applications...what application are you using? It is different to Excel from Access.

Comment: wbeard, yes, there's always a space. Thanks! Charlie, Sorry, I didn't mean to double post. I meant to post with keyword VBA and only after submitting saw it had keyword VB, so I deleted the keyword and reposted, not realizing it went to two separate places.

Comment: What application is this in?

Answer (score 2):

Well, your question is poor, you don't even state if you want this done in Word, Excel etc...

I've assumed Excel. So, this will either do what you want, or give you a good start! 
It reads value in column A and spits the results out into column B.

```
Sub FormatMePlease()

Dim row As Integer
row = 1

Do While (True)

    If Range("A" & row).Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
    End If

    Dim originalValue As String
    originalValue = Range("A" & row).Value
    originalValue = Replace(originalValue, Chr(34), "") 'chr(34) is double quote
    originalValue = Replace(originalValue, "-", "") 'be gone oh evil dash
    originalValue = Replace(originalValue, "  ", " ") 'double white space? Never! Single white space will be more than enough

    Dim result As String

    result = Chr(34)
    For i = 1 To Len(originalValue)

    Dim currentCharacter As String
    currentCharacter = Mid(originalValue, i, 1)

    If (IsNumeric(currentCharacter) Or currentCharacter = " ") Then
        result = result + currentCharacter
    Else
        result = Left(result, i - 1)
        result = result & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34)
        result = result & Mid(originalValue, i)
        Exit For            
    End If

    Next i

    result = result & Chr(34)

    Range("B" & row).Value = result

    row = row + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Screen shot using Excel:

[image]

Comment: Once you hit a non-numeric character, you are done. Use `mid(foo,i)` and then `exit for` You don't need to iterate to the end of each string.